# Speech to Text (RecongnitionListener) changing prompt for error message

Tags: android, speech-recognition

[image]

While implementing speech to text, I have changed the welcome note prompt "Trying saying something" by using the following line of code.

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Please speak now");
```

but unable to change the error message text "Didn't catch that. Try speaking again" and the label "Try again" shown in the below image. Is it possible to change these two prompts? Thanks

[image]